# any caveats for "deploy to static website" from the Azure extension in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, azure, visual-studio-code

I need to deploy a React app to Azure.  Within VS Code, the Azure extension has a "Deploy to Static Website" menu option.  I'm not totally clear on the constraints around "static" website.  At what point is a React website no longer considered "static" and will therefore require an alternative deployment option?  Will a "deploy to static website" option still work if I need to incorporate Axios to make API calls?  Or would this invalidate the React website's status as a "static" website and therefore require some type of alternative deployment option?

Also, I'm currently trying out the deployment process from my laptop and the process is taking a while - it's deploying 33242 files to storage and this is a pretty basic website.  Does a typical deploy static website process for this type of basic website take up to an hour?  Based on the number of files and processing time, it seems like there could be some potential for some high costs.  I just want to be careful about this b/c it's easy to get surprise costs in Azure if you don't totally know what you're doing.

Comment: Static just means you're only serving built HTML/CSS/JS. The Axios calls are made from the client's browser. It seems like you're probably deploying node_modules, though, not just the build output.

Comment: thanks jon - how can I ensure that only the build output gets deployed via the "deploy static website" option?  /node_modules is included in my .gitignore file.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with that tooling.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-static-website-node-04?tabs=react, did you deploy the build directory specifically?